# HTML emails not showing on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, email

So I designed an HTML email and it works for every platform but when testing for specifically Iphone's and using the native mail app on the iphone it comes in blank. Not sure it's the CSS or the HTML itself, but again everything looks fine on desktop and android native mail app

Note: I tried multiple iphones and all of them have the updated IOS version
below is an example of the html.

```
<div class="row clearfix" style="*zoom: 1;">

        <div class="column full" style="width: 100%;float: left;padding-left: 1rem;padding-right: 1rem;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;">

            <div class="center" style="text-align: center;">

                <img id="" src="http://127.0.0.1/EZBZ_new/EZBZ_crm_new/assets/images/uploads/4xwzpei-5mn.png" style="border-radius: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 1.4em 0px 1em;">

            </div>

            <div class="display center" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;text-align: center;">

                <h1 style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;font-weight: 800;letter-spacing: 0px;line-height: 1.4;font-size: 2em;margin: 0.4em 0;text-transform: uppercase;color: #007199;">Lorem Ipsum is Simply</h1>

                <p style="font-size: 1.1em;line-height: 2;font-weight: 300;margin: 1em 0;font-style: italic;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>

            </div>

            <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 1.07em;line-height: 2;font-weight: 300;margin: 1em 0;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus leo ante, consectetur sit amet vulputate vel, dapibus sit amet lectus.</p>

        </div>

    </div>

<div class="row clearfix" style="*zoom: 1;">

        <div class="column third" style="width: 33.3%;float: left;padding-left: 1rem;padding-right: 1rem;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;">

            <h1 style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;font-weight: 300;letter-spacing: 0px;line-height: 1.4;font-size: 2.36em;margin: 0.4em 0;color: #007199;">Lorem Ipsum</h1>

            <p style="font-size: 1.07em;line-height: 2;font-weight: 300;margin: 1em 0;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

        </div>

        <div class="column two-third" style="width: 53.03%;float: left;padding-left: 1rem;padding-right: 1rem;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;">

            <img id="" src="http://crm.ezbz.co/assets/images/uploads/-3y357s.png" style="max-width: 100%; margin: 1.4em 0px 1em;">

        </div>

    </div>.
<div style = "text-align: center;width: 100%;float: left;"><p>To unsubscribe from marketing emails please click <a href="http://myezbz.com/unsubscribe?email=635844@ezbz.co&origin=m"><unsubscribe>here</unsubscribe></a>.</p></div>
```

Comment: for a start, `<img id="" src="http://127.0.0.1/EZBZ_new/EZBZ_crm_new/assets/images/uploads/4xwzpei-5mn.png" style="border-radius: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 1.4em 0px 1em;">` shouldn't work. Its a local link. host it somewhere and then put that link.

Comment: @toing_toing correct but even then it shouldn't affect the rest of the page and I should of seen at least broken img tags but I don't even see any of the HTML

Comment: A screenshot might help any potential helping hand. You may also try with much simpler html5 tags at first and then improve on it. I don't have any iddea why it would not work on ios specifically :(

Comment: The best way to figure it out is to test and debug. Write code using specific parts of the CSS and HTML, keep adding bits here and there until it breaks. And then you'll know the previous addition is at least part of the cause, which will hopefully give you some ideas of why it's happening and how to fix it. It would also help others on SO help you narrow it down even further.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code, including html enclosures, header etc.? Only sending the code above as-is will surely get you into rendering trouble not just on Ios and will get your emails trapped in spam filters for sure. Proper formated html (like it´s 1994) is key